# Dead lock when retrieving several keys from Redis

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to get the result of this queries to redis (using stackexchange C# client) in parallel but somehow I'm running in deadlock and not sure where

The method for retrieving the data:

```
public LiveData Get(string sessionId)
{
    return GetAsync(sessionId).Result;
}

private async Task<LiveData> GetAsync(string sessionId)
{
    var basketTask = GetBasketAsync(sessionId);
    var historyTask = GetHistoryAsync(sessionId);
    var capturedDataTask = GetCapturedDataAsync(sessionId);

    var basket = await basketTask;
    var history = await historyTask;
    var capturedData = await capturedDataTask;

    return new LiveData
    {
        Basket = basket.IsNullOrEmpty
            ? new List<Product>()
            : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(basket),
        History = history.Select(cachedProduct
            => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(cachedProduct.Value.ToString())).ToList(),
        CapturedData = capturedData.ToDictionary<HashEntry, string, object>(
            hash => hash.Name, hash => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(hash.Value))
    };
}
```

And the methods for fetching the cached data from redis are:

```
private async Task<RedisValue> GetBasketAsync(string key)
{
    key = $"{key}{BasketSuffix}";
    var redisDb = RedisConnection.Connection.GetDatabase();
    redisDb.KeyExpireAsync(key, _expire);

    return await redisDb.StringGetAsync(key);
}

private async Task<HashEntry[]> GetHistoryAsync(string key)
{
    key = $"{key}{HistorySuffix}";
    var redisDb = RedisConnection.Connection.GetDatabase();
    redisDb.KeyExpireAsync(key, _expire);

    return await redisDb.HashGetAllAsync(key);
}

private async Task<HashEntry[]> GetCapturedDataAsync(string key)
{
    key = $"{key}{CapturedDataSuffix}";
    var redisDb = RedisConnection.Connection.GetDatabase();
    redisDb.KeyExpireAsync(key, _expire);

    return await redisDb.HashGetAllAsync(key);
}
```

I think it's fine calling the KeyExpireAsync like this, just because it's fine to trigger and forget but not sure if that could be related (I tried even removing it and it's still blocked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the deadlock is this snippet:

```
public LiveData Get(string sessionId)
{
    return GetAsync(sessionId).Result;
}
```

Instead, invoke it the proper way "async all the way":

```
public async Task<LiveData> Get(string sessionId)
{
    return await GetAsync(sessionId);
}
```

Invoking `.Result` can lead to deadlocking, as can using the `.Wait()` API. Also, from the looks of it -- the `.KeyExpireAsync` needs to be awaited.

```
async Task<RedisValue> GetBasketAsync(string key)
{
    key = $"{key}{BasketSuffix}";
    var redisDb = RedisConnection.Connection.GetDatabase();
    await redisDb.KeyExpireAsync(key, _expire);

    return await redisDb.StringGetAsync(key);
}
```

I understand your thought process on not using the `await` keyword on the `.KeyExpireAsync` call but if I were writing this code I would most certainly want to `await` it like I have demonstrated. It is a code smell to have a fire-and-forget, and can be easily avoided.